# Showing that if $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ is exact with $C$ projective, then $0\to A\otimes M\to B\otimes M\to C\otimes M\to 0$ is exact.

Tags: abstract-algebra, alternative-proof

I had a question on a past qual that asked just that, where $M$ was an arbitrary module. The question also said not to use the theory of Tor groups. I was able to show that it using Ext groups, but I don't feel that is in the spirit of what was meant by not using Tor groups. Could anyone help prove that
$$0\to A\otimes M\to B\otimes M\to C\otimes M\to 0$$
is exact provided $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ is exact and $C$ projective? Thank you.

For how I did it with Ext groups, here's a proof sketch:

$$0\to \text{Hom}(C\otimes M,N)\to\text{Hom}(B\otimes M,N)\to \text{Hom}(A\otimes M,N)\to 0$$
is exact by the hom-tensor adjoint theorem iff
$$0\to\text{Hom}(C,\text{Hom}(M,N))\to\text{Hom}(B,\text{Hom}(M,N))\to\text{Hom}(A,\text{Hom}(M,N))\to0$$
is exact. Well Since $C$ is projective the above is exact by the long exact sequence for $\text{Ext}$. Therefore for all $N$
$$0\to \text{Hom}(C\otimes M,N)\to\text{Hom}(B\otimes M,N)\to \text{Hom}(A\otimes M,N)\to 0$$
is exact, hence
$$0\to A\otimes M\to B\otimes M\to C\otimes M\to 0$$
is exact.

Comment: what is your definition of projective?

Comment: @Brian Shin A module that satisfies the Universal Property that if $g:M\to N$ is such that $$M\to N\to 0$$ is exact, and $f:C\to N$ a morphism, then there exists a unique morphism $h:C\to M$ such that $g\circ h=f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $C$ is projective, the sequence $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ splits. Therefore
so does $0\to A\otimes M\to B\otimes M\to C\otimes M\to 0$ which implies it is also exact.

Comment: I'd forgotten about this property, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

First, some notation: let's call these maps $i : A\to B$ and $p: B\to C$.

Next, a lemma: A module $P$ is projective if and only if every short exact sequence
$$ 0 \to M \to N \to P \to 0$$
splits.

Since $C$ is projective, we know the sequence
$$0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$$
splits, i.e. we have a map $q: B\to A$ such that $qi = 1_A$. This tells us that $i \otimes M : A \otimes M \to B\otimes M$ admits a retraction: $q\otimes M$. In particular, we must have that $i\otimes M$ is injective.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot about the splitting property for injectives and projectives.